# Poco С++ Как отправить файл на сервер

Tags: c++, клиент-сервер, poco

Poco разбираюсь с этой библиотекой, появилась задача отправить файл на сервер в интернете, кто то знает как это сделать. ни как не получатся найти информацию. В крайнем случаи возможно использование другой ,библиотеки, но не сurl. Протокол http

Comment: Пока вопрос выглядит слишком общим. Вам надо отправить файл через HTML-форму?

Comment: Судя по предыдущим вопросам ТС, он пишет малварь.

Comment: Я пишу виндовс программу, которая будет слать по запросу с сервера скриншот на сервер,  и исполнять другие команды, С другими командами всё хорошо, но скрин пока что я могу отправить только в текстовом формате, что увеличивает его с 3 до 10 mb. так же сервер не откроет такой формат, по этому еще и клиент конвертер придется писать.